# Add theme support for post thumbnails

Tags: post-thumbnails, add-theme-support

I created a custom post type called `products` without support for thumbnails because I want to add the support for post-thumbnails in functions.php file.
So I use after_setup_theme action hook and use this code:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'products ) );
```

as explained at this link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support#Post_Thumbnails

But I can't find the Featured image box when i create/update product type posts.

I looked up in `add_theme_support` function in theme.php file but I can' fine any reference to post-thumbnails.

Which is the best way to add support and why I can't find any reference to `post-thumbnails` in `add_theme_support` function?

Answer (score 1):

What `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'products' ) );` did is: it added the support for the `post-thumbnail` feature, and with the second parameter you fixed the feature support to only `post_type` = 'products'. But it actually saying: *Ok, load all the necessary things to register a Post Thumbnail* — you're actually introducing 'Post Thumbnail' to WordPress.

But to add/show the "Featured Image" meta box you have to activate the "Post Thumbnail" feature when you are registering the Custom Post Type like below:

```
$args = array(
   'supports' => array( 'title', 'thumbnail' ) //it'll enable the meta box
);
register_post_type( 'products', $args );
```

But with this bit of code you are actually saying: *Ok, you know what [post]'thumbnail' means, now let the user to add one*.

So you will need to add both the theme_support and the post_type support meta box.

Comment: I think the code example in codex is wrong. i better studied the add_theme_support function and it doesn't require args.

Comment: Perhaps the understanding to the code was error-prone. Yes, it doesn't *require* arguments, but it *can take* arguments. You probably missed [Line#1769](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/theme.php#L1769).

Comment: But this happens in current_theme_supports function

Comment: And finally it's filtering `$_wp_theme_features[$feature]` with itself using `add_filter()` ([Line#1810](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/theme.php#L1810)).